# Android draw picture usage

Tags: android

I noticed that there is a drawPicture method on Canvas. From what I read, it seems it would record the sequence of draws call so you don't have to call them again when you need to do the same drawing. That seems very handy but I rarely saw code example using it so  I am assuming my understanding is incorrect.

So, what is canvas.drawPicture and when do you use it

Comment: As the name suggests, `drawPicture()` simply draws a picture on the canvas: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPicture(android.graphics.Picture, android.graphics.Rect)

Comment: If you go into the details description of the method it talks about recording drawing calls and retrieving them. the Picture is not simply "an image". It is an Objects with recording capabilities.